# AWS Cognito: Pass custom attributes for social media logins

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook, amazon-cognito-triggers

I would like to implement a referral program for user signups and am looking to store the referee information as custom attributes in Cognito. I am using Amplify SDK for the same.

I am able to store the custom attributes for custom logins (using email address and password), but how to achieve the same using Social media logins like "Google" and "Facebook"?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but did you find a solution?